# How to appropriately pass arguments to a user-defined function where the arguments are used by another functions that is also passed as an argument

Tags: r, function, syntax, arguments

I want to define a function (`reg`) that has as arguments a function (`f`) and a list of arguments that needs to be passed to this last function, but I am having problems with how to appropriately pass the arguments to the top function (`reg`) so that the passed function (`f`) can use (some or all of) the passed arguments without throwing an error message. Specifically, I have written the following function:

```
library(estimatr)

reg <- function(fm, data = df, f = lm, weights = wgt, 
                clusters = cl, se = 'stata') {
  # Model estimation
  if        (identical(f, lm)) {
    m <- f(as.formula(fm), data = data, weights = weights)
  } else if (identical(f, lm_robust)) {
    m <- f(as.formula(fm), data = data, weights = weights, 
           clusters = clusters, se = se)
  } else {
    stop(paste0('Argument `f` outside the list of possible values: ', 
                'lm, lm_robust'), call. = FALSE)
  }
  
  # Returning results
  return(m)
}
```

But this function is not working. For instance, when I try to run the above function with the default arguments, the function does not seem to recognize the `weights` argument; it returns the following error message:

```
> reg(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)

Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'wgt' not found
```

How do I fix this function so the `weights` and `clusters` arguments in `reg` are properly passed to `f`?

Comment: your argument is called `wgt` but you are using `weights = weights` instead of `wgt` in your function. so you are not passing your input to the commands/functions within your function - which is exactly what your error message tells you

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding what you mean, probably because I'm new to R and I'm thinking in terms of Python. But from my understanding in the context of Python, the right-hand side of `weights = weights` should be the value passed to `reg` (i.e., it uses `wgt` if nothing is specified and uses the value of `weights` if something else is specified). Isn't it the way it works in R? (If I write `weights = wgt` instead of `weights = weights` in `f(as.formula(fm), data = data, weights = weights)` I become unable to eventually specify a different weight.)

Comment: @D.J means (I think) that you need to define the objects `wgt` and `cl`  before you can use them as default parameter values.  `wgt` and `cl` are undefined and `weights` and `clusters` are not passed in your call to `reg`, so when `reg` attempts to pass their default values to `f`, it fails.

Comment: you are of course right DOS - i am not used to seeing values being hardcoded into a function call - and jumbled my explanation (badly). thanks @Limey i couldn't have said it better

Comment: @Limey, thanks for the clarification. In the definition of `reg`, I changed `weights = wgt` to `weights = dft[['wgt']]` and `clusters = cl` to `clusters = dft[['cl']]` and it works.